# Conflicts between SQL BI tools 2005 and SQL BI tools 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm facing conflicts between SQL BI tools of different versions (2005 and 2008). I have SQL BI tools 2008 installed on my PC and when I'm trying to install SQL BI tools 2005 (trying to do this because the part of the project I'm working on is written on VS 2005 and SQL 2005) and it says that i have a later version of the BI component and it halts the installation.

I've tried to uninstall SQL BI tools 2008 (I guess this is a stupid idea) and rerun the installation, but no success.

I've checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233182/are-there-conflicts-between-sql-server-2005-and-sql-server-2008), but I guess this is a little bit different.

Any thoughts, guys?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server BI tools for 2005 and 2008 are compatible, but they are problematic when installed 2008 first, then 2005.  The cleanest, most reliable solution would be to uninstall 2008 before 2005.  Can you explain what prevents the 2008 uninstall from completing?

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple versions of large toolsets parallel on the same PC is almost always a pain. Suggested workaround: fire up a virtual PC, install your other version on that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally made everything work yesterday. The solution was to reinstall both MS SQL Server 2005 and MS SQL Server 2008. The order in which you're installing them matters: you should install 2005 first and then 2008.
I guess this is not the best solution, but it worked for me.